# PyQT: How do I handle loops in main?

Tags: pyqt

I have an application that has a PyQT GUI. I set up the GUI in the usual PyQT fashion:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.initialize()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that right after this I have a while loop that handles signals (signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ...) and also does some other things.  If I call sys.exit(app.exec_()) before the while loop, the loop does not execute. If I call it after the loop, the GUI hangs up. Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

The `app.exec_()` call basically starts 'a while loop that handles [QT] signals' etc. It's the event loop of the program.

You shouldn't need your own loop to do that stuff. If you do, you're talking about multiple threads and you need to look at the docs for [QThread](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qthread.html) and/or [QEventLoop](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qeventloop.html).

You *really* shouldn't need a while loop to handle system signals like SIGINT etc - these are specifically designed so that you 'hook into' them like events, and their occurrence will trigger a function you specify.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way things are done for pyqt4 (and indeed similar for wx, gtk, etc.) is to subclass the widget of choice, which is what presumably your MainWindow is (from QMainWindow?), and populate it with various signals and slots, which are generated by qt's event loop so that you don't explicitly have to worry about them.

You may wish to include the definition of MainWindow, so that we can better understand the context and kinds of events you are interested in.

More specific to your question, if you wanted to intercept the closing of the main window, you could reimplement the following method in MainWindow as shown:

```
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        event.ignore()
```

would prevent your main window from being closed.