# Python - How to show the window + print the text? Where its only printing but not showing the window

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt4

How to show the window + print that text? Where it does not show window anymore if i have my while loop on.

```
import sys
import datetime
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Main, self).__init__(parent)       
    self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("exit", self, clicked=self.close)
    self.c = QtGui.QLabel("Test", self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp=Main()
  myapp.show()     
  while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Print this + Show the Window???!!!"
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tried:

```
import sys
import datetime
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Main, self).__init__(parent)       
    self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("exit", self, clicked=self.close)
    self.c = QtGui.QLabel("Test", self)

  def myRun():
    while True:
      time.sleep(2)
      print "Print this + Show the Window???!!!"      

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp=Main()
  myapp.show()     

  thread = QtCore.QThread()
  thread.run = lambda self: myRun()
  thread.start()    
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

TypeError: () takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQT: How do I handle loops in main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765384/pyqt-how-do-i-handle-loops-in-main)

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: Please see above, not working applied thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues: 1) You're not calling or initializing the thread correctly. 2) You need to tell your main thread to keep processing events while the other thread is running 3) Your label is hovering over the 'exit' button, and therefore you'll not be able to ever click it!

```
import sys
import datetime
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Main, self).__init__(parent)       
    self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("exit", self, clicked=self.close)

  def myRun(self):
    while True:
      time.sleep(2)
      print "Print this + Show the Window???!!!"      

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myapp=Main()
  myapp.show()     

  thread = QtCore.QThread()
  thread.run = lambda myapp=myapp: myapp.myRun()
  thread.start()    

  app.connect(app, QtCore.SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), app, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))

  sys.exit(app.exec_())

  while thread.isAlive():
    #Make sure the rest of the GUI is responsive
    app.processEvents()
```

Comment: Label is fine, i used it so that no mouse can click it but explicitly keyboard `space` bar need to be used.

Comment: What exactly this lines do? `app.connect(app, QtCore.SIGNAL("lastWindowClosed()"), app, QtCore.SLOT("quit()"))` where is that lastWindowClosed() and quit() from that line?

Comment: @YumYumYum That is a signal from the [QApplication](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qapplication.html) class which calls the `quit()` cleanup actions for the class reference when the last window in the stack is closed. It is essentially an implict cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda self: myRun()` tries to invoke the global function `myRun()`. Try

```
lambda myapp=myapp: myapp.myRun()
```

instead. The odd assignment will create a default parameter because `thread.run()` doesn't get one.

Comment: same still `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/tmp/python-hack-the-mac/src/Test.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    thread.run = lambda myapp=myapp: myapp.myRun()
TypeError: myRun() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: That should be `def myRun(self):`